# Как рендерить данные (только с type=3)?

Tags: vue.js

В `data()` у меня лежат `orders`

Как потом "рендерить" результат выполнения этой функции

```
getType3Orders() {
    this.orders=this.orders.filter(item => item.type===3)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим:

> В data() у меня лежат orders

Вывести некоторые из этих данных можно путем встраивания выражения в шаблон:

```
<div id="app">
   {{ orders.filter(item => item.type===3) }}
</div>
```

либо воспользовавшись [вычисляемым свойством](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) из `computed`:

```
computed: {
  getType3OrdersComp() {
    return this.orders.filter(item => item.type === 3)
  }
 }
```

либо воспользовавшись [методом](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods) из `methods`:

```
methods: {
  getType3OrdersFunc() {
   return this.orders.filter(item => item.type === 3)
  }
 }
```

Каждый способ имеет свои особенности и это следует учитывать при выборе способа вывода данных.

Привожу пример всех трех способов

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    orders: [{
        id: 1,
        type: 1,
      },

      {
        id: 2,
        type: 2,
      },

      {
        id: 3,
        type: 3,
      }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    getType3OrdersComp() {
      return this.orders.filter(item => item.type === 3)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getType3OrdersFunc() {
      return this.orders.filter(item => item.type === 3)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ orders.filter(item => item.type===3) }}
  <hr> {{ getType3OrdersComp }}
  <hr> {{ getType3OrdersFunc() }}
</div>
```

Comment: Работает но , почему ошыбки в консоле ???

Comment: опишите текст ошибки

Comment: this.orders.filter is not a function

Comment: по всей вероятности у вас `orders` в `data` либо не определен либо не является массивом, поэтому и пишет, что метод `filter()` не является функцией (так как `filter` применяется к массивам), обратите внимание на приведенный мною пример. Если бы вы в вопросе дали больше информации о вашем `orders` я бы включил это в пример

Comment: Спасибо, у меня orders: ' ' был ))) ахахха сделал [] масивом )))